# Host parameter in NodeJS webserver

Tags: node.js

I am sorry if this is a silly question, but I really have to know. 
Below code implements a simple web server with NodeJS. If I don't pass host parameter to listen event, server will be still listening on the localhost(127.0.0.1), and if I pass anything other than 127.0.0.1 it will not work! So What is a real scenario where we need to provide an actual host IP to the listen event ? because with my limited knowledge, I can't think of anything.

```
var http = require("http");
console.log("Web server started");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 1337;


var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

    console.log("received request: " + req.url);

    res.writeHead(200,{"content-type":"text/plain"});

    res.end("hello world");

});

server.listen(port,host,function(){
    console.log("listening: "+host+ ": " +port);
});
```

I appreciate your insight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback):

> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.

Limiting which addresses a server listens to allows you to such things as:

- Listen only on localhost so that your unfinished code which may still have security holes isn't exposed to everybody on your LAN.
- Listen on a LAN facing IP address but not an Internet facing IP address (e.g. if you were writing software to run on a router) so that your business could use the software but Joe Random Internet Passerby can't.

> if I pass anything other than 127.0.0.1 it will not work!

That suggests that either:

- You are trying to bind to an IP address that does not belong to your computer *or*
- You are trying to make the HTTP request to the wrong IP address

Comment: Thank you Mr. Quentin, your explanation helped me a lot. Out of curiosity, What if I want to expose my webserver on my lan ? what do I need to do ? Is it even possible ?

I tried to bind my webserver to 127.0.0.2. is this a wrong IP ? is there a valid IP which I can use instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: You'd have to use an IP address that your computer actually had on the LAN.